# Issue loading web fonts in I.E 11 - some browsers, not all browsers

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I've looked around SO and found many questions and answers that address fonts not loading in I.E

What I haven't found, is a question/answer to fonts not loading in **some instances** of I.E

My `@font-face`'s look like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sans_condensedbold';
    src: url('/content/fonts/opensans-condbold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/content/fonts/opensans-condbold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/content/fonts/opensans-condbold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/content/fonts/opensans-condbold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/content/fonts/opensans-condbold-webfont.svg#open_sans_condensedbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

There are many of these.

At times, some clients browsers are just not loading the fonts.

My machine; they're fine. The guy next to me, they don't load. Some clients call in with the same issues.

Some things we've tried.

- Not running in compatibility mode
- Running in compatibility mode (breaks some other things)
- Deleting all temp files

They just won't load for some client browsers.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, Who doesn't think that this is about programming and in the scope of SO? And why?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found the issue.

Because it was happening on only some versions of I.E it seemed to be more a setup of the browser.

Essentially, 'Font Download' was disabled in internet options:

[image]